# Python adding to dictionary wth multiple values from file ..getting error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am getting error ..list out of range with this code.. can someone help pls?

```
def classGrade(infile):
    inf=open(infile)
    contents=inf.readlines()
    inf.close()

    classg={}
    for line in contents:
        y=line.split("\t")
        d={}
        print(y)

        d['id']=y[0]
        d['exam1']=y[1]
        d['exam2']=y[2]
        d['homework']=y[3]
        d['attendance']=y[4]
        d['project']=y[5]
        d['classrecap']=y[6]

        classg[y[0]]=d
    print(classg)
print (classGrade('mock1.txt'))
```

Comment: Looks like `mock1.txt` is bad.

Comment: Add a `print(y)` after the split. Bet there's a blank line.

Comment: You are going to have to re-check the contents of `mock1.txt`. If possible, you may show a sample of its contents to us (by adding it to your question post).

Comment: Looks like you're splitting on tabs (`\t`) -- Are you sure that those are tabs and not spaces? (Your text editor may use spaces for the tab key)

Comment: please update the txt file or give a sample